# Groupby based on selected condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following table

```
+----+-----+--------+------------+
| ID | Age | Amount |    Date    |
+----+-----+--------+------------+
|  0 |  50 |     57 | 01/01/2001 |
|  0 |  63 |    206 | 02/01/2001 |
|  2 |  32 |     27 | 03/01/2001 |
|  0 |  61 |    613 | 04/01/2001 |
|  1 |  30 |    929 | 05/01/2001 |
|  0 |  62 |     59 | 06/01/2001 |
|  1 |  32 |    430 | 07/01/2001 |
|  1 |  24 |    561 | 08/01/2001 |
+----+-----+--------+------------+
```

How can i perform a groupby operation that only runs on the rows that match a certain condition`, leaving the other rows unaltered?

For example, my condition is ID == 1, and i want to perform the following operations:

Age - get the mean value

Amount - get the sum

Date - get the last date

Expected result:

```
+----+------+--------+------------+
| ID | Age  | Amount |    Date    |
+----+------+--------+------------+
|  0 | 50   |     57 | 01/01/2001 |
|  0 | 63   |    206 | 02/01/2001 |
|  2 | 32   |     27 | 03/01/2001 |
|  0 | 61   |    613 | 04/01/2001 |
|  1 | 28.7 |   1920 | 08/01/2001 |
|  0 | 62   |     59 | 06/01/2001 |
+----+------+--------+------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
>>> df.loc[df['ID'] == 2, 'Value'] = sum(df.loc[df['ID'] == 2, 'Value'])
>>> df.drop_duplicates()
   ID  Value
0   2     20
1   0      9
2   1      0
4   0     10
```

**EDIT**:

1. If you want to sum multiple cols:

```
>>> df
   ID  Value  col3
0   2      7     8
1   0      9    10
2   1      0     1
3   2      4     5
4   0     10    11
5   2      9    10
>>> df['col3'] = df['Value'] + 1

>>> df.loc[df['ID'] == 2, ['Value', 'col3']] = (df.loc[df['ID'] == 2, ['Value', 'col3']]
                                                .sum().values)
# if you have many cols, then instead of specifying the cols as list, use this:
# df.loc[df['ID'] == 2, df.columns[1:]] = (df.loc[df['ID'] == 2, df.columns[1:]]
#                                                .sum().values)
>>> df.drop_duplicates()
   ID  Value  col3
0   2     20    23
1   0      9    10
2   1      0     1
4   0     10    11
```

2. If you want to sum only `Values` but keep other columns:

```
>>> df
   ID  Value  col3
0   2      7     8
1   0      9    10
2   1      0     1
3   2      4     5
4   0     10    11
5   2      9    10

>>> df.loc[df['ID'] == 2, 'Value'] = sum(df.loc[df['ID'] == 2, 'Value'])
>>> df.drop_duplicates(subset = ['ID', 'Value'])
   ID  Value  col3
0   2     20     8
1   0      9    10
2   1      0     1
4   0     10    11
```

**EDIT 2**:

Based on your latest edit, `pd.DataFrame.agg()` might be best suited for you:

```
>>> df
+----+-----+--------+------------+
| ID | Age | Amount |    Date    |
+----+-----+--------+------------+
|  0 |  50 |     57 | 01/01/2001 |
|  0 |  63 |    206 | 02/01/2001 |
|  2 |  32 |     27 | 03/01/2001 |
|  0 |  61 |    613 | 04/01/2001 |
|  1 |  30 |    929 | 05/01/2001 |
|  0 |  62 |     59 | 06/01/2001 |
|  1 |  32 |    430 | 07/01/2001 |
|  1 |  24 |    561 | 08/01/2001 |
+----+-----+--------+------------+
>>> df2 = df[df['ID'] == 1]
>>> df.loc[df['ID'] == 1, df.columns[1:]] = (df2.agg({'Age':['mean'], 
                                                      'Amount':['sum'], 
                                                      'Date':[lambda x:x.iloc[-1]]
                                                      })
                                                .bfill()
                                                .ffill()
                                                .reset_index(drop=True)
                                                .values)
>>> df.drop_duplicates()

   ID        Age  Amount        Date
0   0  50.000000    57.0  01/01/2001
1   0  63.000000   206.0  02/01/2001
2   2  32.000000    27.0  03/01/2001
3   0  61.000000   613.0  04/01/2001
4   1  28.666667  1920.0  08/01/2001
5   0  62.000000    59.0  06/01/2001
```

Comment: That might work. But what if i had multiple columns instead of just 1 (Value)?

I made this table just for example demonstration and totally forgot of that detail. (my bad)

Comment: Do you mean to say you want to sum up values in multiple columns? Or do you want to sum only for `Values` column, but there might be other columns?

Comment: @ricardo, u could update ur post to include more columns

Comment: @SayandipDutta thanks :) that was it! For the time being i only need to do sums so that solution will work.
Still i updated the post because i might need a more complex approach in the future.

I will wait a bit and probably mark this one as the correct answer.

Comment: @RicardoVilaça updated to your latest edit. You may upvote if you find it useful :)

Comment: smooth. i think yours is the better option. could you show me how you copy the tables successfully? i have tried copying this markdown type tables and i have never been successful

Comment: Lol, neither could I. Copied the marked down, stored it in a triple quoted string (`s`). Used: `print(s.replace('+', '').replace('|', '').replace('-', ''))`, copied that :D

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that- What's the best way to put a table on SO? I honestly don't know

Answer (score 1):

This pulls out the conditional rows (ID eq 1), does a groupby on them and store the output in a conditional_groupby variable.
Find the indices for the conditionals in the original dataframe, keep the first row, and discard the rest. insert groupby in the saved index.

```
conditional_groupby = (df.copy()
                    .query('ID==1')
                    .groupby('ID').agg(Age=('Age','mean'),
                                       Amount=('Amount','sum'),
                                       Date = ('Date','last'))
                    .reset_index()
                    )

drop_them = df.loc[df.ID==1].index[1:]
insert_point = df.loc[df.ID==1].index[0]
df = df.drop(drop_them)

df.loc[insert_point] = conditional_groupby.iloc[0]
df['Age'] = df.Age.round(2)
```

Comment: Came up with the same solution, at the same time :D

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
df=(
    df.drop(df.loc[df["ID"]==1].index, axis=0)
    .append(
       df.loc[df["ID"]==1].groupby("ID", as_index=False)
       .agg({"Age": "sum", "Amount": "sum", "Date": "last"})
    , ignore_index=True)
    )
```

Outputs:

```py
   ID  Age  Amount        Date
0   0   50      57  01/01/2001
1   0   63     206  02/01/2001
2   2   32      27  03/01/2001
3   0   61     613  04/01/2001
4   0   62      59  06/01/2001
5   1   86    1920  08/01/2001
```